The pivot chart does not refresh with the 'Refresh All' button
I have an Excel file that contains a table. In the same Excel file, I perform a Power Query on this table and then load it into Power Pivot.
In Power Pivot, I create two measures (NB_KO and NB_OK) and then create a pivot chart based on these measures.
I have a chart showing the number of KO and OK.
When I change the KO and OK values in the source table and click on the "Refresh All" button in the Data tab:
The values are updated in the Power Query query.
The data model and measures are updated in Power Pivot.
The pivot chart is not updated.
To see the changes take effect in the pivot chart, I have to check "Defer Layout Update" and click the "Update" button at the bottom to finally see the changes.
Do you have a solution to make the changes visible with just the "Refresh All" button?
Thanks
(https://i.sstatic.net/2V2rJeM6.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/HlFI28NO.png)
pivot chart should update automatically

I believe this is expected, since Pivot Tables use the Pivot Cache. This site suggests you can either manually refresh, or use VBA to run a refresh whenever your worksheet changes.

This worked for me when none of the other suggestions would work:

Left click on pivot chart.
Left click on "PivotChart  Analyze" .
Left click on "Clear" pull down menu.
Left click on "Clear All." Note that chart will disappear until next step.
Left click on "Undo". Pivot table returns, and data is now updated!

